Formula para extraer varios criterios
Busco una formula que me permita presentar el resultado de varios criterios, ejemplo
tengo varios almacenes con varias ubicaciones.
Condición debe ser si la denominación del centro 100 q la sucursal es sur, y el almacén es S001, entonces debe salir Alimentos
Centros 100 - 200 - 300
Sucursal Norte, sur, centro sur, centro norte, almacenes S001 S002 S003 S005, la denominación Del almacén es alimento, químicos, repuestos.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! tu pregunta asi como esta, no tiene sentido.. podrias ser mucho mas clara?

Te recomiendo que añadas datos de ejemplo y el resultado esperado con Tablas Markdown. Por favor, lee Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable y no olvides leer ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?. Visita también el  tour

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
